# Supermarket evaluation and rating in France

Tags: online-resources, france, shopping, burgundy

I am going to be spending a few weeks in France renting a house, so I was wondering if there are any online or other service that rate local supermarket chains or grocery stores in France.

US has [Consumer Reports](http://www.consumerreports.com) which rates chains overall and [Yelp](http://www.yelp.com) to review the individual locations.  [Yelp](http://www.yelp.com) is available in France since it bought Cityvox but the information is still pretty scarce.

So is there something that can supplement this information?

Comment: Do you need to know anything in particular about each supermarket? Would an answer listing supermarkets with good services be sufficient?

Comment: @NathanShoesmith Some details would be helpful.  List of chains I can probably google.

Comment: What details though?

Comment: @NathanShoesmith Availability of organic, general cleanliness and quality of products, average prices, any other details that may be available.  As I said I can google the list of chains but an independent evaluation will give me a starting point to look further.

Comment: **Grand Frais** is a national treasure.  **E Leclerc** is the best supermarket.   The market (saturday mornings, etc) in Beaune is obviously world-famous.  (But incredibly overpriced - the very many famous chefs in the area go straight to Grand Frais, the one by the autoroute exit.) You need to explain what you're looking for in a supermarket, Karlson.  Why not state the town youa re in or near and we'll tell you the best or closest!

Comment: @JoeBlow I am not looking for which supermarket location is closest to me I am looking for the information on their product line and service.  I've already put the location where I will be staying on the map and searched for "Supermarket" nearby which gave me a list of 20+ locations.  As I said there are overall information available in the US in publications like Consumer Reports about various supermarket chains I am looking for similar information for France.  Because while I will be staying in 1 location 2.5 hour drive for attractions isn't out of the question.

Comment: Hi Karlson, that does not really exist. You will find it incredibly different.  Regarding price, if you shop price, cancel the holiday now and go to Sussex or Alabama instead  :)  E. Leclerc is the best supermarket, by far.  You won't be disappointed.  Note that the worst "ordinary" supermarket in France has staggeringly better food than the "gourmet" chains (eg, WholeFoods) in the US.  Carrefour is also good.  the Mousquetaires, Intermarche, one is a bit more discount.  Given that you are on holiday and spending thousands to get there it is unlikely you will pass E Leclerc as a tourist...

Comment: One visit to a Grand Frais and your life will be changed, enjoy!  If you want hard-core, localvore (as you'd say in the States), organic stuff just go to the Beaune Market (saturday / wednesday mornings right?).  You will find the best (example) Bressan chicken breeders there.  for truly elite produce you have to get to know eg. the sommelier etc. at restaurants you frequent and they will happily send you to producers in the countryside.

Comment: if you want literally an "organic food store" the only real choice is l'Odyseé Bio (trivial to find with google) in Beaune, indeed rather close to the Grand Frais and E Leclerc.

Comment: Finally, if you literally want to know "Who is the best butcher" or "Which is the best greengrocer" I mean those are questions of national importance; it would be as difficult as saying "What's a good white wine in Meursault" you know!!  The only answer would be a big argument. Try a few in your village and the other villages.  For most visitors, the biggest question is "Which is the best boulangerie", you can live there for six years and debate it every day, with great pleasure.  I hope, you enjoy!

Comment: @JoeBlow Even spending thousands I am not looking to spend more thousands to feed myself.  And driving 2.5 for shopping would be insane but stopping at a local store to pick up some stuff on the way home isn't.  Secondly I am not looking for the best.  I am looking for an independent publication or site or something that does the evaluation rather than ones opinions on the subject.  Lastly as far as "What's a good white wine in Meursault" is simply asking how do you like your Chardonnay or Aligote but that is an entirely different discussion.

Comment: Hi Karlson, I believe the best answer to your question is that really such a web site or comparative guide, **does not in fact exist**.  It's a fact that internet-social-media is sort of "behind" in France; they're just not as in to it.  If there was such an online (or other) comparative guide, I'd know and there is not. I hope that "negative" information helps in some way.  {Conceivably, it may be worth asking a different question along the lines of "staying near X, what options exist with these qualities [value, organic - whatever] nearby?"}

Comment: @JoeBlow Than that should be the answer.

Comment: If you are staying in a rural area, you might not have that much choice. If you are staying next to a bigger city, the bigger stores are not that different from each other.

Comment: @Relaxed I am staying 20 minutes from Dijon but again travelling in the 2.5 hour range by car.   So I may look elsewhere just to pick up something locally where I am is possible so question is phrased fairly generic intentionally.

Answer (score 5):

Food in France is very "local". As said before you will not find a centralized listing of what is on offer and where. You need to ask the locals, the owners of your vacation house, the tourist office where you can shop and for what. There are several large supermarkets where I stay in France and there is very little between them, the one I prefer has a great butcher counter but that's due to the staff, and might not be the same in other areas. 
If you are set on organic foods then you should ask for health shops or "vitamin" shops that usually sell a good range of veggies and fruits but it's not cheap. I don't find that supermarkets carry a lot of organic produce. 
When looking at markets, I have learned to distinguish between those who sell fresh produce but from all over to those whose focus is very local from small farmers using less intensive methods. Again some research on a local level is necessary. I hope this helps.

Comment: Care to list a few that you know carry more local fare?

Comment: Hi, Where I go the most local are cooperatives regrouping local farmer produce. You would have to ask locally (tourist office?) to see if there is an equivalent. In my "Super U" supermarket I find local eggs and meat from local farms and then a small selection of organic produce and organic shelf stable products.

Comment: What do you mean about food being very local? France is actually home to some huge retail chains (Carrefour, E.Leclerc, Auchain...) and big-box stores are more common there than in many neighbouring European countries. And they obviously carry organic food nowadays, at least in the bigger stores.

Comment: I agree about big box chains but along side you have lots of local sources that it would be a shame to ignore. Honestly I don't find big supermarkets  organic selections are up to much, it depends what type of food you want to buy.

Comment: @Relaxed: Those two factors are not mutually exclusive. At least in Germany, large retail chains are very wide-spread. Each of the chains standardizes their stores in many aspects, and much information about the stores, current offers, etc. is available online. At the same time, the stores are subject to quite some variation, depending on individual factors such as size of the store and possibly also individual decisions of the respective manager. As a consequence, I usually find it impossible to find out whether a particular product is available in a particular store without going there.

Comment: "vitamin" shops? If anyone asked me for a vitamin shop in France I would not be able to locate even a single one. For organic food, ask for organic shops ("bio" in French). Anyone will be able to direct you to one.

Comment: Bio shops often sell "supplements alimentaires" or in other words vitamins. To get back to the original question I dont think you will find the centralized  listing. You have to decide what you want first ( bio, local, cheap prices?) then ask locally what shops/markets correspond best to those choices.

Comment: @CCazes Fair enough but that's a different approach. Organic food is now widely available, even if you personally prefer something else.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I am quite familiar with Germany and I don't think you can say that food is "very local" there either, probably even less than in France. France does have many different cuisines and some local products are more difficult to find outside of their region of origin. But that's just a bit of variation, not much more than that.

Comment: @Relaxed: For what it's worth, even within the same supermarket chain, the contents of the cooled pasta shelf seems to differ quite a bit between, say, Baden-Württemberg and Berlin. But regional variation (and Germany does have various different cuisines, as well) is not what I understood by "local"; I interpreted it more like the concrete suppliers operate on very local levels and hence, the quality of some products might differ from town to town rather than nation-wide from retail chain to retail chain.

Comment: Just to chime in: The supermarkets in the US prefer in season to source product locally since it saves on Storage, Transportation, and obviously raises profit margins  But this doesn't preclude them from sourcing necessary products elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to buy food in France :
- go for small stores like butcher and baker. Those usually offer the best quality but the price could be expensive.
- go to the supermarket. You have small, medium and hypermarket. The bigger the supermarket is, the more choice you'll have. Supermarket offer a selection of local products and national brand products. Pricing is usually the cheapest and quality can vary. You'll also find organic (bio) shopd but price are really expensive.
- go to the fresh market that you'll find twice a week in most of the towns. You'll find there freshest products usually coming directly from the farm.

Few advices to eat good food :
- buy local products rather than products coming from the other side of the earth. You'll find a lot of fruits coming from a lot of foreign countries. They have traveled a lot so I let it to you to guess what they are made of to be able to absorb the travel delay...
- ask the locals. People will be delighted to give you directions to the best shop.
- ask the store staff, they will also give you ideas to discover seasonnal good products.
- check the shops where is a queue up to the exit, this is usually a good sign.
- check for awards. Best shops received awards and are usually very proud to highlight those. Shops without awards aren't necessary bad but shops that received awards are definitely good.

You'll find some reviews on Google local business listing and also the pages jaunes but usually not a lot. So rather ask locals. You will see them walking with their little caddy in the street in the morning.